# Where to store global state variable in MVC and how to pass it around?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

Please help me understand this aspect of MVC architecture.

Let's say my app can be in two global states, **view mode** and **edit mode**.

1/
The mode needs to be saved to backend so when the app loads again it will be in the same mode.

2/
The mode can be changed in the main menu (that is part of my view code).

3/ Other visual elements and model functionality depend on the mode state. Certain things will not be visible in view mode and saving will work differently as well.

4/ My app can load external modules on demand that need to be aware of the mode state when they load and of it's further changes.

Because of the loose coupling of the modules I was thinking the best practice would be to dispatch an event on mode change. My question is: **where do I dispatch it from? Where is the variable actually defined? In model? In view? How does view and model code access this variable? How is it passed between model and view? What is the role of the controller in this case?**

NOTE: it does not really matter but my code is in JavaScript and I have not settled for any framework yet.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear which platform you're using, but I think these suggestions might be mostly platform independent.

First of all this doesn't sound like a true application global state attribute, but rather a user or session attribute.

If you want your app to remain "pure" stateless, this edit mode data should be part of the models/viewmodels you send to and receive from the front end.  Your controllers can then read and react to the mode change and modify the value as appropriate before sending to your front end. And the front end JS can also read and change the value as appropriate.

Also though, the standard session should also be available too and can be used but of course that breaks the "statelessness" of your app.

Comment: You are probably right but I wish you would provide more details.

Comment: Happy to, but I'm working in asp.net mvc so will details help you if I expand on this?